# How can I parse the part number for this IC?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have a PCB board of a SMPS circuit and in this board an IC term as:

"660-03
C102204
UC1848 "

I have searched a lot over net to find this component but not successfully. Does anyone have any kind of info about this component?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a standard UC1848. You can easily find a datasheet from multiple manufacturers with terms "UC1848 data sheet pdf".

Comment: I search uc1848 also but 1848 is a 16 pin current pwm controller ic but in the smps board I have 8 pin ic. So I hope it can not be uc1848.